# vs2003: project not getting built

Tags: visual-studio

I have vs2003 c# solution with multiple projects. It seems like project1 in sln file is not getting built and is not producing the desired DLL. Project2 depends on project1.dll and is getting build errors. How do I insure that project1 gets built. Do I have to change some sort of build property like Debug vs Release. The DLLs are supposed to build in the obj/Debug folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you build a solution it shows build details in output window so you can find out what is the problem with project1. it also writes the details to a log file. at least copy the details and paste it here so i can help more. and no, normally your project should be built under both debug and release mode.

Comment: where is that log file stored?

Comment: by default it is in your build directory. you can also find it in the build output message. look at this: "Build log was saved at "file://d:\workspace\test\Serv\Debug\BuildLog.htm"". i copied it from my build output window.